# How to merge map result in to one array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, ecmascript-6

The object result restructuring function works fine at the same time the map result not coming in one array group.

```js
console.clear();
const filterList = {
  ageRange: ["ageRange", "picAgeRange"],
  goal: ["goal", "motivation"],
  hairColor: ["hairColor", "picHairColor"]
};

const questionList = [{
    question: "ageRange",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "18-30",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "31-35",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "36-45",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "46-55",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "55+",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "picAgeRange",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "country 6",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "smart casual 4",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "dark denim 6",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "sporty 6",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "adventure 5",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "prints 5",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "excentric 5",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "dont like any private style",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "goal",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "save time",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "personal advice",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "inspiration",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "testing the service",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "hairColor",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:49.567",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "blond",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "brown",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "black",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "red",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "grey",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "noHair",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "picHairColor",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "suit 3",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "business casual",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "casual",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "have to wear uniform",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "classic",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "conservative",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "relaxed 2",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "dont like any work style",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  }
];

const ofQuestionsList = Object.entries(filterList).map(
  ([questionKey, questionNames]) => {
    return {
      [questionKey]: questionList.filter((item) =>
        questionNames.includes(item.question)
      )
    };
  }
);
console.log(ofQuestionsList);
```

The existing result is

```
[
  {
    "ageRange": [
      {
        "question": "ageRange",
        "lastUpdated": "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
        "info": null,
        "type": "SELECT"
      },
      {
        "question": "picAgeRange",
        "lastUpdated": "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
        "info": null,
        "type": "SELECT"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "goal": [
      {
        "question": "goal",
        "lastUpdated": "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
        "info": null,
        "type": "SELECT"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "hairColor": [
      {
        "question": "hairColor",
        "lastUpdated": "2018-07-09T18:13:49.567",
        "info": null,
        "type": "SELECT"
      },
      {
        "question": "picHairColor",
        "lastUpdated": "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
        "info": null,
        "type": "SELECT"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expecting result is

```
{
  "ageRange":[
    {
      "question":"ageRange",
      "lastUpdated":"2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
      "info":null,
      "type":"SELECT"
    },
    {
      "question":"picAgeRange",
      "lastUpdated":"2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
      "info":null,
      "type":"SELECT"
    }
  ],
  "goal":[
    {
      "question":"goal",
      "lastUpdated":"2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
      "info":null,
      "type":"SELECT"
    }
  ],
  "hairColor":[
    {
      "question":"hairColor",
      "lastUpdated":"2018-07-09T18:13:49.567",
      "info":null,
      "type":"SELECT"
    },
    {
      "question":"picHairColor",
      "lastUpdated":"2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
      "info":null,
      "type":"SELECT"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array, for your case if I understood correctly you want to group your elements and return them in one results object.

This seems like something that can be achieved with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), so you would have:

```
const ofQuestionsList = Object.entries(filterList).reduce(
  (acc, [questionKey, questionNames]) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [questionKey]: questionList.filter((item) =>
        questionNames.includes(item.question)
      )
    };
  }, {});
```

This reduce takes 2 parameters, a callback taking the `accumulator` and your `current element` that being processed in your array. And the `accumulator`'s initialization with an empty object `{}`.

Then in each iteration we return a merged object with the previous values of the iterator, and the current one

```js
console.clear();
const filterList = {
  ageRange: ["ageRange", "picAgeRange"],
  goal: ["goal", "motivation"],
  hairColor: ["hairColor", "picHairColor"]
};

const questionList = [{
    question: "ageRange",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "18-30",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "31-35",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "36-45",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "46-55",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "55+",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "picAgeRange",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "country 6",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "smart casual 4",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "dark denim 6",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "sporty 6",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "adventure 5",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "prints 5",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "excentric 5",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "dont like any private style",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "goal",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "save time",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "personal advice",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "inspiration",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "testing the service",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "hairColor",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:49.567",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "blond",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "brown",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "black",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "red",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "grey",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "noHair",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "picHairColor",
    lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
    info: null,
    type: "SELECT",
    answers: [{
        value: "suit 3",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: "business casual",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "casual",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "have to wear uniform",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "classic",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "conservative",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "relaxed 2",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        value: "dont like any work style",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  }
];

const ofQuestionsList = Object.entries(filterList).reduce(
  (acc, [questionKey, questionNames]) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [questionKey]: questionList.filter((item) =>
        questionNames.includes(item.question)
      )
    };
  }, {});

console.log(ofQuestionsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Manage with result

```js
console.clear();
const result = [{
    ageRange: [{
        question: "ageRange",
        lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
        info: null,
        type: "SELECT"
      },
      {
        question: "picAgeRange",
        lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
        info: null,
        type: "SELECT"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    goal: [{
      question: "goal",
      lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
      info: null,
      type: "SELECT"
    }]
  },
  {
    hairColor: [{
        question: "hairColor",
        lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:49.567",
        info: null,
        type: "SELECT"
      },
      {
        question: "picHairColor",
        lastUpdated: "2018-07-09T18:13:42.541",
        info: null,
        type: "SELECT"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var newObj = result.reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, b), {})

console.log(newObj)
```